# how many squence $a_1, \dots ,a_n$ there are so that the product of $a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot \dots \cdot a_n$ divisible by 10?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

i have to provide how many squences $a_1, \dots ,a_n$ with $a_i\in \{1,\dots,9\}$ so that the product of $a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot \dots \cdot a_n$ divisible by 10?

how can i begin with this problem?

Comment: Hint: The desired conclusion holds if and only of both $5$ and an even number are among your sequence.

Answer (score 3):

- $a=$ number of sequences, matching or not the condition.
- $b=$ number of sequences that do not contain $5$.
- $c=$ number of sequences that have only odd digits.
- $d=$ number of sequences whose digits are among $1,3,7,9$

Result $=a-b-c+d$

Comment: Might just note that the formula comes from inclusion-exclusion... (good hint)